# iOS Auto Layout 6 Rectangles Same Size Universal Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to make a layout which has 6 rectangles with different background colors. They should all be the same height, with no space in-between each one. The page should also have no margin. Everything is within a scrollview.

I am doing all of this within the auto layout in x-code.

I have tried setting constraints of each view's top and bottom to 0 then, I held shift selected all of the Views and set equal heights. But it does not make them equal at all, and there is space between each view.

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The heights look equal to me.  Th edges just aren't touching.  You can constrain the bottom of view1 to the top of view2 and so on but since simple UIViews have no intrinsic content size you are probably going to have to give auto layout some clue as to how high each view should be

Comment: You can do this by setting an aspect ratio constraint between the height of your first view and the height of the scroll view of 1:6

Comment: add your screen to a sample project and post on git or somewhere. i will correct it for you. your problem is scrollview id not getting its content height thats why this is happening. you need to add vertical space 0 between each view and equal height to all views among each other and top space from the top view to the scrollview and bottom space from the bottom view to the scrollview. But this is not enough. you need to give proportional height from any one view to the superview of scrollview. because at least one height constraint is needed in scrollview which is fixed from outside.